# How to send data using jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

this is my html

```
<!-- <form action="view.php" method="post">  -->
        <input type="text" name="text" id="name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <!-- </form> -->
```

I don't want to send the data by using form Couse it only send named attribute data that's why I am sending data by $.ajax() method
and this is script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var details = {};
    $('input[type="submit"]')
        .click(function () {
            details = { name: $('input[type="text"]').val() };
            $.post({
                url: "view.php",
                method: "post",
                data: details,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("done")}
             });
           window.open('view.php','_self');
});});
```

after all this thing i want to retrieve the data on view.php file
but i am fail to achieve it on that file it is showing the array is empty

```
<?php
var_dump( $_POST);
//the array is empty
?>
```

suggest me something please.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request and the request made from `window.open` are two different requests. Think of it like two different phone calls that you'd receive... And having absolutely no "memory" of the conversation at the end. You would need a database for that "memory" and it's something else.

To send some data to the backend (to process it) and want to have a result back into the original page, use the `success` callback.

HTML in original page:

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="name">
<input type="button" value="submit">
<div id="backendResult"></div>
```

JS in original page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var details = {};
  $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    details = { name: $('input[type="text"]').val() };
    $.post({
      url: "view.php",
      method: "post",
      data: details,
      success: function (result) {
        console.log("done")
        $('#backendResult').html(result)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

view.php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo 'Hello '.$name.'!';
?>
```

Comment: But when we use

Comment: But when i use <form action="view.php"> it is posting the data to view.Php file and open that too, am I right or wrong

Comment: I assumed you removed the form (it is commented out in your question). So Ajax is sending the data to view.php AND is coming back with a result.

Comment: Yes you are right it is commented because I want to make that function by ajax. I want to sand my data to view.Php file and want to move on that(view.php) file too with access of that data, what action attribute do in form tag

Comment: The usefulness of ajax is to get some additionnal data for the current page without navigating. If you want to navigate to `view.php`, then just submit the form.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var details = {};
    $('input[type="submit"]')
        .click(function () {
            details = { name: $('input[type="text"]').val() };
            $.post({
                url: "view.php",
                method: "post",
                data: details,
                success: function (result) {  // {name : 'the text you typed'}
                    console.log("done")
                    $("body").load('view.php', function(){
                       $("#name").val(result.name);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: But when I use `<form action=view.php>` of html it post the data and open that file too, I am wrong or right